# How to map a specific index in my array to an html table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to map specific data from this array that's returned from my API and list it onto a table that's created by jQuery. However, I only need specific data from this array to be displayed and not the whole thing. The array is listed below and the amount of data that is returned is fairly large. I only need to map through the data: "raw_value": [] and then from there I only need the last 10 data points, so in this case I would need to start at the data point 2850. I know how to map through an entire array, but I'm not sure how to start at a specific value. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

This is the ajax call I use to access the API. The data gets stored in response and then parsed. Then I try to map through parsed obj at the end.

```
const modelApi = function () {
       

        $.ajax({
            url: `api_url`,
            method: 'GET',
            error: function (xhr) {
                if (xhr.status === 504) {
                    modelApi()
                    $('.overlayMessage').text('Server not responding, trying your search again. Please do not refresh the page')
                }
                if (xhr.status === 502) {
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut()
                    alert('No data was returned for your current search criteria. Please try selecting a different meter or a different date range')
                }
            }
        }).then(response => {
            const obj = JSON.parse(response.body)
            console.log(obj)
           
        obj.map(data, () => {
            
        })
```

```
{
    "building": {
        "building_abbreviation": "ECJ",
        "building_number": "0227",
        "use_type": "Laboratory",
        "aliases": null,
        "is_dorm": 0,
        "cooling_commodity": "CHW",
        "heating_commodity": "STM"
    },
    "meter": "2032",
    "commodity": {
        "tag": "S"
    },
    "model": {
        "x": "hdd",
        "train_start": "2019-05-01",
        "train_end": "2020-04-29",
        "analysis_start": "2020-05-01",
        "analysis_end": "2020-05-31",
        "iqr_errors": [
            {
                "lower_bound": -6684.776494485483,
                "upper_bound": 7416.929568407427
            }
        ],
        "auto_ignored_percentage": 20.454545454545453,
        "search": {
            "base_temperatures": [
                10,
                11,
                12,
                13,
                14,
                15,
                16,
                17,
                18,
                19,
            ],
            "r2_scores": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
               
            ]
        },
        "base_temperature": 84,
        "max_train_r2": 0.4810672409755815,
        "slope": 474.72313695289665,
        "intercept": 3058.7897948225855,
        "std": {
            "analysis": 2126.1299232079455,
            "train": 6244.513670227164
        },
        "data": {
            "timestamp": [
                "2019-05-01",
                "2019-05-02",
                "2019-05-03",
                "2019-05-04",
                "2019-05-05",
                "2019-05-06",
                "2019-05-07",
                "2019-05-08",
                "2019-05-09",
                "2019-05-10",
                
            ],
            "average_dry_bulb_temperature": [
                77.9,
                69.4,
                68.7,
                71.1,
                73.8,
                71.8,
                74.7,
                71.8,
                75.9,
                60.8,
                60.6,
                68.9,
                70.5,
                73.2,
                75.2,
                76.5,
                79.3,
                79.2,
                82.9,
                81.3,
                78.3,
                82.2,
                
            ],
            "degree_day": [
                6.099999999999994,
                14.599999999999994,
                15.299999999999997,
                12.900000000000006,
                10.200000000000003,
                12.200000000000003,
                9.299999999999997,
                12.200000000000003,
                8.099999999999994,
                23.200000000000003,
                23.4,
                15.099999999999994,
                13.5,
                10.799999999999997,
                8.799999999999997,
                7.5,
                4.700000000000003,
                4.799999999999997,
                1.0999999999999943,
                2.700000000000003,
                5.700000000000003,
                1.7999999999999972,
                1.4000000000000057,
                2.0999999999999943,
                3.200000000000003,
                3,
                4.099999999999994,
                4.099999999999994,
                1.5999999999999943,
                6.599999999999994,
                3,
                1.2000000000000028,
              
            ],
            "raw_value": [
                1420,
                3920,
                8170,
                8270,
                7170,
                3230,
                2900,
                5140,
                6060,
                4970,
                15260,
                15780,
                5030,
                4800,
                5900,
                5660,
                5420,
                4720,
                4740,
                4550,
                4490,
                4710,
                1960,
                770,
                1970,
                4020,
                4630,
                4600,
                4180,
                2930,
                2490,
                4090,
                4580,
                3160,
                1680,
                3460,
                4730,
                5160,
                2140,
                2570,
                4060,
                2860,
                3280,
                1230,
                470,
                1000,
                3370,
                4380,
                4490,
                4480,
                3960,
                1730,
                1730,
                4820,
                4970,
                2720,
                3430,
                4540,
                4970,
                3320,
                1270,
                2280,
                3660,
                4160,
                3670,
                2520,
                3820,
                3810,
                3440,
                3230,
                2050,
                3640,
                2950,
                2900,
                3110,
                930,
                530,
                330,
                2290,
                3810,
                3940,
                3820,
                2060,
                2880,
                3820,
                3940,
                3940,
                1990,
                3880,
                3850,
                3780,
                3040,
                3570,
                2870,
                3030,
                3260,
                2850,
                3410,
                1650,
                3790,
                3760,
                2850,
                3170,
                2540,
                3440,
                3320,
               
            ],
            "preprocessed_value": [
                1420,
                3920,
                8170,
                8270,
                7170,
                3230,
                2900,
                5140,
                6060,
                null,
                15260,
                15780,
                5030,
                4800,
                5900,
                5660,
                5420,
                4720,
                4740,
                4550,
                4490,
                4710,
                1960,
                770,
                1970,
                4020,
                4630,
                4600,
                4180,
                2930,
                2490,
                4090,
                4580,
                3160,
                1680,
                3460,
                4730,
                5160,
                2140,
                2570,
                4060,
                2860,
                3280,
                1230,
                470,
                1000,
                3370,
                4380,
                4490,
                4480,
                3960,
                1730,
                1730,
                4820,
                4970,
                2720,
                3430,
                4540,
                4970,
                3320,
                1270,
                2280,
                3660,
                4160,
                3670,
                2520,
                3820,
                3810,
                3440,
                3230,
                2050,
                3640,
                2950,
                2900,
                3110,
                930,
                530,
                330,
                2290,
                3810,
                3940,
                3820,
                2060,
                2880,
                3820,
                3940,
                3940,
                1990,
                3880,
                3850,
                3780,
                3040,
                3570,
                2870,
                3030,
                3260,
                2850,
                3410,
                1650,
                3790,
                3760,
                2850,
                3170,
                2540,
                3440,
                3320,
                2870,
                1570,
                2580,
                3700,
                1500,
                4000,
                3560,
                3560,
                3810,
                3020,
                1580,
                3460,
                3760,
                3710,
                3070,
                2930,
                3620,
                2180,
                3280,
                2900,
                2930,
                2380,
                2590,
                3410,
                1230,
                3180,
                3280,
                3570,
                3090,
                3140,
                2970,
                3100,
                3910,
                3670,
                3610,
                3590,
                3510,
                3210,
                3940,
                3710,
                3670,
                3630,
                3020,
                3360,
                3160,
                3410,
                3260,
                3140,
                3650,
                3700,
                3810,
                3820,
               
            ],
            "null_reason": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                "IQR boundary error",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
            
            ],
            "predicted_value": [
                5954.600930235252,
                9989.747594334873,
                10322.053790201902,
                9182.718261514954,
                7900.965791742133,
                8850.412065647926,
                7473.714968484523,
                8850.412065647926,
                6904.047204141046,
                14072.36657212979,
                14167.311199520367,
                10227.10916281132,
                9467.552143686691,
                8185.799673913868,
                7236.3534000080745,
                6619.2133219693105,
                5289.988538501201,
                5337.460852196487,
                3580.985245470769,
                4340.542264595408,
                5764.7116754540975,
                3913.291441337798,
                3723.4021865566438,
                4055.7083824236656,
                4577.903833071856,
                4482.959205681275,
                5005.154656329459,
                5005.154656329459,
                3818.3468139472175,
                6191.9624987117,
                4482.959205681275,
                3628.4575591660628,
                3296.1513632990336,
                3296.1513632990336,
                5764.7116754540975,
                5005.154656329459,
                6286.907126102282,
                3818.3468139472175,
                3201.206735908453,
                3201.206735908453,
                5289.988538501201,
                7853.493478046839,
                6191.9624987117,
                4672.848460462437,
                4435.486891985988,
                3153.734422213166,
                3058.7897948225855,
                6381.8517534928615,
                3723.4021865566438,
                3058.7897948225855,
                3058.7897948225855,
                3058.7897948225855,
                3296.1513632990336,
                3058.7897948225855,
                7995.910419132713,
                5717.239361758804,
                5289.988538501201,
                4577.903833071856,
                3913.291441337798,
                3580.985245470769,
                7331.298027398655,
                4055.7083824236656,
                4008.236068728379,
                5100.099283720039,
             
            ],
            "predicted_value_lower_bound": [
                -6534.4264102190755,
                -2499.279746119455,
                -2166.9735502524254,
                -3306.3090789393736,
                -4588.061548712195,
                -3638.6152748064014,
                -5015.312371969805,
                -3638.6152748064014,
                -5584.980136313282,
                1583.3392316754616,
                1678.2838590660394,
                -2261.918177643007,
                -3021.4751967676366,
                -4303.22766654046,
                -5252.673940446253,
                -5869.814018485017,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -7151.56648825784,
                -8908.042094983559,
                -8148.48507585892,
                -6724.31566500023,
                -8575.73589911653,
                -8765.625153897683,
                -8433.318958030663,
                -7911.123507382472,
                -8006.068134773052,
                -7483.872684124869,
                -7483.872684124869,
                -8670.68052650711,
                -6297.064841742627,
                -8006.068134773052,
                -8860.569781288264,
                -9192.875977155294,
                -9192.875977155294,
                -6724.31566500023,
                -7483.872684124869,
                -6202.120214352046,
                -8670.68052650711,
                -9287.820604545876,
                -9287.820604545876,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -4635.533862407488,
                -6297.064841742627,
                -7816.17887999189,
                -8053.5404484683395,
                -9335.29291824116,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -6107.175586961466,
                -8765.625153897683,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9192.875977155294,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -4493.116921321614,
                -6771.787978695524,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -7911.123507382472,
                -8575.73589911653,
                -8908.042094983559,
                -5157.729313055673,
                -8433.318958030663,
                -8480.79127172595,
                -7388.9280567342885,
                -9002.986722374133,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -8765.625153897683,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -8480.79127172595,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -8053.5404484683395,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9002.986722374133,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -8860.569781288264,
                -8243.429703249501,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9002.986722374133,
              
            ],
            "predicted_value_upper_bound": [
                18443.62827068958,
                22478.774934789202,
                22811.081130656232,
                21671.745601969284,
                20389.99313219646,
                21339.439406102254,
                19962.74230893885,
                21339.439406102254,
                19393.074544595373,
                26561.393912584117,
                26656.338539974695,
                22716.136503265647,
                21956.579484141017,
                20674.827014368195,
                19725.380740462402,
                19108.24066242364,
                17779.015878955528,
                17826.488192650817,
                16070.012585925097,
                16829.569605049735,
                18253.739015908424,
                16402.318781792124,
                16212.429527010972,
                16544.735722877995,
                17066.931173526184,
                16971.986546135602,
                17494.181996783787,
                17494.181996783787,
                16307.374154401545,
                18680.989839166028,
                16971.986546135602,
                16117.484899620391,
                15785.178703753361,
                15785.178703753361,
                18253.739015908424,
                17494.181996783787,
                18775.93446655661,
                16307.374154401545,
                15690.23407636278,
                15690.23407636278,
                17779.015878955528,
                20342.520818501165,
                18680.989839166028,
                17161.875800916765,
                16924.514232440317,
                15642.761762667495,
                15547.817135276913,
                18870.879093947187,
                16212.429527010972,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15785.178703753361,
                15547.817135276913,
                20484.93775958704,
                18206.26670221313,
                17779.015878955528,
                17066.931173526184,
                16402.318781792124,
                16070.012585925097,
                19820.325367852984,
                16544.735722877995,
                16497.263409182706,
                17589.126624174365,
                15975.067958534522,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                16212.429527010972,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                16497.263409182706,
                17779.015878955528,
                16924.514232440317,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15975.067958534522,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
             
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either get the length of that array, and write a `for` loop with matching start- and end conditions, or use `Array.slice` to extract only the wanted portion of the array first, and then iterate over that ...

Comment: The slice option worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array slice can help you.

```js
let obj = {
    "building": {
        "building_abbreviation": "ECJ",
        "building_number": "0227",
        "use_type": "Laboratory",
        "aliases": null,
        "is_dorm": 0,
        "cooling_commodity": "CHW",
        "heating_commodity": "STM"
    },
    "meter": "2032",
    "commodity": {
        "tag": "S"
    },
    "model": {
        "x": "hdd",
        "train_start": "2019-05-01",
        "train_end": "2020-04-29",
        "analysis_start": "2020-05-01",
        "analysis_end": "2020-05-31",
        "iqr_errors": [
            {
                "lower_bound": -6684.776494485483,
                "upper_bound": 7416.929568407427
            }
        ],
        "auto_ignored_percentage": 20.454545454545453,
        "search": {
            "base_temperatures": [
                10,
                11,
                12,
                13,
                14,
                15,
                16,
                17,
                18,
                19,
            ],
            "r2_scores": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
               
            ]
        },
        "base_temperature": 84,
        "max_train_r2": 0.4810672409755815,
        "slope": 474.72313695289665,
        "intercept": 3058.7897948225855,
        "std": {
            "analysis": 2126.1299232079455,
            "train": 6244.513670227164
        },
        "data": {
            "timestamp": [
                "2019-05-01",
                "2019-05-02",
                "2019-05-03",
                "2019-05-04",
                "2019-05-05",
                "2019-05-06",
                "2019-05-07",
                "2019-05-08",
                "2019-05-09",
                "2019-05-10",
                
            ],
            "average_dry_bulb_temperature": [
                77.9,
                69.4,
                68.7,
                71.1,
                73.8,
                71.8,
                74.7,
                71.8,
                75.9,
                60.8,
                60.6,
                68.9,
                70.5,
                73.2,
                75.2,
                76.5,
                79.3,
                79.2,
                82.9,
                81.3,
                78.3,
                82.2,
                
            ],
            "degree_day": [
                6.099999999999994,
                14.599999999999994,
                15.299999999999997,
                12.900000000000006,
                10.200000000000003,
                12.200000000000003,
                9.299999999999997,
                12.200000000000003,
                8.099999999999994,
                23.200000000000003,
                23.4,
                15.099999999999994,
                13.5,
                10.799999999999997,
                8.799999999999997,
                7.5,
                4.700000000000003,
                4.799999999999997,
                1.0999999999999943,
                2.700000000000003,
                5.700000000000003,
                1.7999999999999972,
                1.4000000000000057,
                2.0999999999999943,
                3.200000000000003,
                3,
                4.099999999999994,
                4.099999999999994,
                1.5999999999999943,
                6.599999999999994,
                3,
                1.2000000000000028,
              
            ],
            "raw_value": [
                1420,
                3920,
                8170,
                8270,
                7170,
                3230,
                2900,
                5140,
                6060,
                4970,
                15260,
                15780,
                5030,
                4800,
                5900,
                5660,
                5420,
                4720,
                4740,
                4550,
                4490,
                4710,
                1960,
                770,
                1970,
                4020,
                4630,
                4600,
                4180,
                2930,
                2490,
                4090,
                4580,
                3160,
                1680,
                3460,
                4730,
                5160,
                2140,
                2570,
                4060,
                2860,
                3280,
                1230,
                470,
                1000,
                3370,
                4380,
                4490,
                4480,
                3960,
                1730,
                1730,
                4820,
                4970,
                2720,
                3430,
                4540,
                4970,
                3320,
                1270,
                2280,
                3660,
                4160,
                3670,
                2520,
                3820,
                3810,
                3440,
                3230,
                2050,
                3640,
                2950,
                2900,
                3110,
                930,
                530,
                330,
                2290,
                3810,
                3940,
                3820,
                2060,
                2880,
                3820,
                3940,
                3940,
                1990,
                3880,
                3850,
                3780,
                3040,
                3570,
                2870,
                3030,
                3260,
                2850,
                3410,
                1650,
                3790,
                3760,
                2850,
                3170,
                2540,
                3440,
                3320,
               
            ],
            "preprocessed_value": [
                1420,
                3920,
                8170,
                8270,
                7170,
                3230,
                2900,
                5140,
                6060,
                null,
                15260,
                15780,
                5030,
                4800,
                5900,
                5660,
                5420,
                4720,
                4740,
                4550,
                4490,
                4710,
                1960,
                770,
                1970,
                4020,
                4630,
                4600,
                4180,
                2930,
                2490,
                4090,
                4580,
                3160,
                1680,
                3460,
                4730,
                5160,
                2140,
                2570,
                4060,
                2860,
                3280,
                1230,
                470,
                1000,
                3370,
                4380,
                4490,
                4480,
                3960,
                1730,
                1730,
                4820,
                4970,
                2720,
                3430,
                4540,
                4970,
                3320,
                1270,
                2280,
                3660,
                4160,
                3670,
                2520,
                3820,
                3810,
                3440,
                3230,
                2050,
                3640,
                2950,
                2900,
                3110,
                930,
                530,
                330,
                2290,
                3810,
                3940,
                3820,
                2060,
                2880,
                3820,
                3940,
                3940,
                1990,
                3880,
                3850,
                3780,
                3040,
                3570,
                2870,
                3030,
                3260,
                2850,
                3410,
                1650,
                3790,
                3760,
                2850,
                3170,
                2540,
                3440,
                3320,
                2870,
                1570,
                2580,
                3700,
                1500,
                4000,
                3560,
                3560,
                3810,
                3020,
                1580,
                3460,
                3760,
                3710,
                3070,
                2930,
                3620,
                2180,
                3280,
                2900,
                2930,
                2380,
                2590,
                3410,
                1230,
                3180,
                3280,
                3570,
                3090,
                3140,
                2970,
                3100,
                3910,
                3670,
                3610,
                3590,
                3510,
                3210,
                3940,
                3710,
                3670,
                3630,
                3020,
                3360,
                3160,
                3410,
                3260,
                3140,
                3650,
                3700,
                3810,
                3820,
               
            ],
            "null_reason": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                "IQR boundary error",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
            
            ],
            "predicted_value": [
                5954.600930235252,
                9989.747594334873,
                10322.053790201902,
                9182.718261514954,
                7900.965791742133,
                8850.412065647926,
                7473.714968484523,
                8850.412065647926,
                6904.047204141046,
                14072.36657212979,
                14167.311199520367,
                10227.10916281132,
                9467.552143686691,
                8185.799673913868,
                7236.3534000080745,
                6619.2133219693105,
                5289.988538501201,
                5337.460852196487,
                3580.985245470769,
                4340.542264595408,
                5764.7116754540975,
                3913.291441337798,
                3723.4021865566438,
                4055.7083824236656,
                4577.903833071856,
                4482.959205681275,
                5005.154656329459,
                5005.154656329459,
                3818.3468139472175,
                6191.9624987117,
                4482.959205681275,
                3628.4575591660628,
                3296.1513632990336,
                3296.1513632990336,
                5764.7116754540975,
                5005.154656329459,
                6286.907126102282,
                3818.3468139472175,
                3201.206735908453,
                3201.206735908453,
                5289.988538501201,
                7853.493478046839,
                6191.9624987117,
                4672.848460462437,
                4435.486891985988,
                3153.734422213166,
                3058.7897948225855,
                6381.8517534928615,
                3723.4021865566438,
                3058.7897948225855,
                3058.7897948225855,
                3058.7897948225855,
                3296.1513632990336,
                3058.7897948225855,
                7995.910419132713,
                5717.239361758804,
                5289.988538501201,
                4577.903833071856,
                3913.291441337798,
                3580.985245470769,
                7331.298027398655,
                4055.7083824236656,
                4008.236068728379,
                5100.099283720039,
             
            ],
            "predicted_value_lower_bound": [
                -6534.4264102190755,
                -2499.279746119455,
                -2166.9735502524254,
                -3306.3090789393736,
                -4588.061548712195,
                -3638.6152748064014,
                -5015.312371969805,
                -3638.6152748064014,
                -5584.980136313282,
                1583.3392316754616,
                1678.2838590660394,
                -2261.918177643007,
                -3021.4751967676366,
                -4303.22766654046,
                -5252.673940446253,
                -5869.814018485017,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -7151.56648825784,
                -8908.042094983559,
                -8148.48507585892,
                -6724.31566500023,
                -8575.73589911653,
                -8765.625153897683,
                -8433.318958030663,
                -7911.123507382472,
                -8006.068134773052,
                -7483.872684124869,
                -7483.872684124869,
                -8670.68052650711,
                -6297.064841742627,
                -8006.068134773052,
                -8860.569781288264,
                -9192.875977155294,
                -9192.875977155294,
                -6724.31566500023,
                -7483.872684124869,
                -6202.120214352046,
                -8670.68052650711,
                -9287.820604545876,
                -9287.820604545876,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -4635.533862407488,
                -6297.064841742627,
                -7816.17887999189,
                -8053.5404484683395,
                -9335.29291824116,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -6107.175586961466,
                -8765.625153897683,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9192.875977155294,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -4493.116921321614,
                -6771.787978695524,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -7911.123507382472,
                -8575.73589911653,
                -8908.042094983559,
                -5157.729313055673,
                -8433.318958030663,
                -8480.79127172595,
                -7388.9280567342885,
                -9002.986722374133,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -8765.625153897683,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -8480.79127172595,
                -7199.0388019531265,
                -8053.5404484683395,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9002.986722374133,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -8860.569781288264,
                -8243.429703249501,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9430.237545631742,
                -9002.986722374133,
              
            ],
            "predicted_value_upper_bound": [
                18443.62827068958,
                22478.774934789202,
                22811.081130656232,
                21671.745601969284,
                20389.99313219646,
                21339.439406102254,
                19962.74230893885,
                21339.439406102254,
                19393.074544595373,
                26561.393912584117,
                26656.338539974695,
                22716.136503265647,
                21956.579484141017,
                20674.827014368195,
                19725.380740462402,
                19108.24066242364,
                17779.015878955528,
                17826.488192650817,
                16070.012585925097,
                16829.569605049735,
                18253.739015908424,
                16402.318781792124,
                16212.429527010972,
                16544.735722877995,
                17066.931173526184,
                16971.986546135602,
                17494.181996783787,
                17494.181996783787,
                16307.374154401545,
                18680.989839166028,
                16971.986546135602,
                16117.484899620391,
                15785.178703753361,
                15785.178703753361,
                18253.739015908424,
                17494.181996783787,
                18775.93446655661,
                16307.374154401545,
                15690.23407636278,
                15690.23407636278,
                17779.015878955528,
                20342.520818501165,
                18680.989839166028,
                17161.875800916765,
                16924.514232440317,
                15642.761762667495,
                15547.817135276913,
                18870.879093947187,
                16212.429527010972,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15785.178703753361,
                15547.817135276913,
                20484.93775958704,
                18206.26670221313,
                17779.015878955528,
                17066.931173526184,
                16402.318781792124,
                16070.012585925097,
                19820.325367852984,
                16544.735722877995,
                16497.263409182706,
                17589.126624174365,
                15975.067958534522,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                16212.429527010972,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                16497.263409182706,
                17779.015878955528,
                16924.514232440317,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15975.067958534522,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
                15547.817135276913,
             
            ]
        }
    }
};

let rawValues = obj.model.data.raw_value;
let last10 = rawValues.slice(Math.max(rawValues.length - 10, 1))
console.info(last10);
```